# Computer keeps shutting off r9 290x

Tags: graphics-card, shutdown, overheating

Hi I've got some issues with my pc.. It keeps turning it self off. It turns off in 3 ways..

1. The machine will turn off and the fans will be on gentle power, perhaps 30-40%
2. The machine will turn off and the fans will be on full power for a long period of time
3. The display will go to sleep, the machine is still on, but there is no way to wake it back up (I've disabled sleep in power management, and its a decent dell u2713h screen)

The problem mainly happens when playing BF4 and has gotten a tiny bit worse. I can't play one game without it playing up. I've got the stock BF4 sapphire R9 290X and I keep my computer clean, un-obstructed etc. I run speedfan to manually overide than fan speeds to 80-90% while playing games, the temps go up to around 80-90 themselves. The card is rated to run at 95 degrees as far as I'm aware...

I don't get any BSOD or anything, so I'm a tiny bit confused. I built the rig as a x-mas present for myself.. I'm not a kid or a dumb adult, I consider myself to have some knolwege when it comes to computers.. And yes, I wear anti-static wristbands grounded to the radiators, besides the its quite humid, so static isn't much of an issue where I live.

I can only think of the issue being related to overheating/faulty card. But it may be something else...

http://uk.pcpartpicker.com/p/XmNNxr (My part list, I've got the BF4 sapphire r9 290x, it wasn't listed)

Comment: This sounds rather similar to an issue I had with BF3. I'd play for a little bit and my card (a superclocked 4gb EVGA GTX 670) would "overheat" (the temperature only being <70F) and cause what I called the "Rainbow Screen of Death", due to the seemingly random colored screen it would output on crash. I RMA'd the card and it kept happening with the new one, so I was led to believe that it was a game problem. Now I know you're playing BF4 but I wasn't able to fix my problem in BF3 ultimately wound up quitting the game.

Comment: Really don't want to quit. Granted I don't game as much as I used to, but I can't go without BF4, it's the only game I play :(

Comment: Quitting is a bit of an extreme but I had exhausted every available resource at my disposal. Hopefully your problem can be resolved without too many issues. I wish I had some more information regarding a possible fix for you. The only thing I really noticed was that the issues started happening after one of the close quarters updates.

Comment: I hope so too. I might RMA it if I can't get it sorted :(

Comment: Pull the side off the computer case, and put a box fan  blowing cool air in the side (or any fair sized fan you have laying around). If you can play for hours that way, then you probably could just adjust your case cooling, improve the flow.  Cranking up the GPU fan to keep the shown temps to 80*c or below, could test to see if it is GPU specific. It sounds somewhat like the GPU is doing a "gpu recover" but it is not recovering.  Use furmark testing to determine if it is the GPU processor OR the GPU ram by doing artifact testing (race through ram) with it.

Comment: Your power supply could bit a low, I would personally go with a 700w or 750w.

Comment: My Mistake, its a 650w bronze plus corsair M PSU. The card shouldn't draw more than 400w at its peak. Obviously there are the other components... I could try using a separate power supply to power it...

I've got the 650m and a older HYPER 400/500w PSU. What would be best to power what? 

Was thinking the HYPER to power mobo, cpu and drives and the 650 for just the r9 290x?

Comment: I've hooked up my 580w to my cpu header and the 650 is powering the mobo, gpu, drives. Seems to be doing fine. 

Is there anything I should be aware of when doing this? Never used two PSU's until now...

Comment: It shut down after getting into a bf4 game. 

Putting the power draw at the extremes...
Asrock z87 extreme6 = 90w
2 x HDD = 30w
1 x SSD = 3w
RAM = 25w
R9 290X = 400w
Is being ran by a 650w Corsair M

4770K = 170w
Is being ran by a hyper 580w...

Why :(

Comment: Psyco, I've got an industrial fan taht I could use, although it sounds louder than the r9 290x @ 100%! Haha

I don't quite think its heat as I don't get any error or BSOD. But yet it seems to happen around the 90 degree mark...

Comment: Well, I've got my big ass fan on full power against my rig.. It seems to be helping. My temps are staying around the 60-80 mark. But I honestly thought the R9 290X was ok at 95c, at least it was before.